# Possible to have text flow underneath all radio buttons?

Tags: html, css

```css
.recommends-Form-radioGroupContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="gds-FormField">
    <legend class="gds-FormField-label">Your Health</legend>
    <input name="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral[health_status]" value="" type="hidden">
    <div class="gds-FormField-control recommends-Form-radioGroupContainer">
      <div>
        <input id="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_excellent" required="required" type="radio" value="excellent" name="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral[health_status]">
        <label for="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_excellent" class="gds-Button gds-Button--ghost recommends-Form-radioLabel recommends-Form-radioLabel--withHint">Excellent</label>
        <p class="gds-FormField-help recommends-Form-help" style="text-overflow: unset;">This is a short, jargon-free explanation of "Preferred Plus" without those actual words in it. It should explain the basics, but not too much.</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_good" required="required" type="radio" value="good" name="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral[health_status]">
        <label for="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_good" class="gds-Button gds-Button--ghost recommends-Form-radioLabel recommends-Form-radioLabel--withHint">Good</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_fair" required="required" type="radio" value="fair" name="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral[health_status]">
        <label for="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_fair" class="gds-Button gds-Button--ghost recommends-Form-radioLabel recommends-Form-radioLabel--withHint">Fair</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_poor" required="required" type="radio" value="poor" name="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral[health_status]">
        <label for="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_poor" class="gds-Button gds-Button--ghost recommends-Form-radioLabel recommends-Form-radioLabel--withHint">Poor</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
```

Any thoughts on best approach to get `p` text (will eventually have a separate `p` text or tip for each button, which will be shown when that button is selected) to flow underneath all radio buttons?

Also, wanting to have the `p` remain under the selected button even when the browser is resized and the buttons are stacked (i.e not like this)

[image])

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what you mean? Are you referring to the `p`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes, the `p`

Comment: Can you alter your `HTML`?

Comment: @sol yep, most definitely possible :)

Comment: Could you provide a mock of what it should look like? I'm not following this - you want the `<p>` under all radios, but you want it under the selected button, that feels like wanting `true` to equal `false` for me.

Comment: @Brian sorry, essentially each button would have a separate tip associated with it, so when one radio button is selected it is expected to show the associated tip beneath the radio button. Also, I'll put together a screenshot here

Comment: @Brian https://d26dzxoao6i3hh.cloudfront.net/items/1j1w2L1f060F3e0J1B2d/Image%202017-12-15%20at%2010.50.51%20AM.png?v=1cd9dcc5 , does that help?

Comment: @Brian and here's what it would look like with your approach https://d26dzxoao6i3hh.cloudfront.net/items/2x0z0x210s22163n1J0g/Image%202017-12-15%20at%2010.52.59%20AM.png?v=a0b4bac5 (also an approach I had tried :/), problem is I'm wanting to the label under the selected button

Comment: Ah alright, I'm going to delete my answer. I'll try to look a bit more in a little bit. I'm not one of those CSS gods unfortunately. Is this pure HTML/CSS or do you have any JS?

Comment: Yeh, haha, me either haha. Would prefer a no js solution, but I can have js if need be

Comment: I've used the HTML & CSS above, and it doesn't look like your screenshot. Is there some other css you are using?

Comment: @JonathanChaplin Yeah there’s a bunch of extra css for the stylings, but I’ve included what I️ thought would be relevant and be able to demonstrate the behavior, but can include more if you need

Comment: Please do, It would help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? 
You could remove, the `flex:1;` property if you don't want them to be flexible and remove the `align-items and justify-content` which I just added for alignment.

> **How is it being aligned?**
>
> I've made use of `relative and absolute positioning` on parent (the outermost div) 
>   and child element (p tag) and initally hidden all the `<p>` tags and when 
>   the radio button is checked, the associated `sibling <p> with that
>   specific class` is shown.

```css
.recommends-Form-radioGroupContainer{
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
}

.recommends-Form-radioGroupContainer *{
  flex:1; 
}

.recommends-Form-radioGroupContainer .gds-FormField-help{
display:none;
padding:5px;
border:3px solid lightblue;
color:blue;
background:rgba(60,60,256,0.1);
position:absolute;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .gds-FormField-help{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="gds-FormField">
    <legend class="gds-FormField-label">Your Health</legend>
    <input name="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral[health_status]" value="" type="hidden">
    <div class="gds-FormField-control recommends-Form-radioGroupContainer">
      <div>
        <input id="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_excellent" required="required" type="radio" value="excellent" name="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral[health_status]">
        <label for="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_excellent" class="gds-Button gds-Button--ghost recommends-Form-radioLabel recommends-Form-radioLabel--withHint">Excellent</label>
        <p class="gds-FormField-help recommends-Form-help" style="text-overflow: unset;">This is a short, jargon-free explanation of "Preferred Plus" without those actual words in it. It should explain the basics, but not too much.</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_good" required="required" type="radio" value="good" name="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral[health_status]">
        <label for="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_good" class="gds-Button gds-Button--ghost recommends-Form-radioLabel recommends-Form-radioLabel--withHint">Good</label>
        <p class="gds-FormField-help recommends-Form-help" style="text-overflow: unset;">Another long message that you will type to check if it works</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_fair" required="required" type="radio" value="fair" name="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral[health_status]">
        <label for="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_fair" class="gds-Button gds-Button--ghost recommends-Form-radioLabel recommends-Form-radioLabel--withHint">Fair</label>
        <p class="gds-FormField-help recommends-Form-help" style="text-overflow: unset;">And this is also one of them other long messages</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_poor" required="required" type="radio" value="poor" name="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral[health_status]">
        <label for="recommends_insurance_term_life_referral_health_status_poor" class="gds-Button gds-Button--ghost recommends-Form-radioLabel recommends-Form-radioLabel--withHint">Poor</label>
        <p class="gds-FormField-help recommends-Form-help" style="text-overflow: unset;">Last long message I promise</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: thank you! close; any way to handle this: https://d26dzxoao6i3hh.cloudfront.net/items/2W0r3U4305453i390U0G/Image%202017-12-15%20at%201.13.06%20PM.png?v=d5d443c8

Comment: @Drew Did you try to apply the flex:1; property?

Comment: yeh, but to no avail

Comment: @Drew I've updated my answer. I'm not sure about the rest of your CSS but it could be interfering. Try this out. or you know the problem is arising because of the Poor that is being wrapped in the next row. If you remove the row-wrap I think it would work fine, because of it the popup doesn't get any space to show up since your html is structured the way it is, there's not many options.

Comment: @Drew No problem :) Don't forget to mark it up. Cheers